# fastai 'TextDataLoaders' is not defined error

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I run this on locally on jupyter notebook, I didn't get any error, but while running the same code on Google Colab I got the error

Code >

```
from fastai.text.data import *
dls_lm = TextDataLoaders.from_df(train_df, path=path, is_lm= True, valid_pct=0.1, bs=128)
```

Error >

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-6b25f76bb852> in <module>()
----> 1 dls_lm = TextDataLoaders.from_df(train_df, path=path, is_lm= True, valid_pct=0.1, bs=128)

NameError: name 'TextDataLoaders' is not defined

[image: Local][image: Colab]

Answer (score 0):

You can import like this to make it work.

> ```
> from fastai.text.data import TextDataLoaders
> ```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?